# kendo datepicker not show after publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a project that use kendo datepicker for showing my date time. On localhost, I don't have a problem, but when publishing my website, kendo datepicker is not shown correctly. How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure the Kendo library is packaged with the compilated/packaged version you publish.

Comment: Check for console errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

yeah . my console log is :Mixed Content: The page at 'https://"MyAddress"' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. https not allow to load kendo cdn